# Why does function `strtoll` gives a wrong value and set errno to 34?

Tags: c, strtol

Here's my C code:

```c
    char *ptr = "0xfff1342809062Cac";
    char *pEnd;
    long long value = strtoll(ptr, &pEnd, 0);
    printf("%lld\n", value);
    printf("errno: %d\n", errno);
```

I compiled it with gcc-8.3.0, and the output is:

```
9223372036854775807
errno: 34
```

I'm confused that strtoll gives an unexpected value and set errno to 34.

Comment: In such cases the first step should be to call `perror` or `strerror`, and/or look up the error code.

Comment: The call to `printf("%lld\n", value);` can munge `errno`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, Better to call `printf("errno: %d\n", errno);` first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is correct. On your system the maximum value for `long long`, i.e. `LLONG_MAX` is `9223372036854775807`.

The value in your string is larger than this; and the specified behaviour if the value is out of range and too big is: return `LLONG_MAX` and `errno` is set to `ERANGE` (presumably 34 on your system).

Perhaps consider using `strtoull` and an `unsigned long long` return value , since that string would fit in that data type.

Comment: In the posted code, the value of `errno` does not necessarily indicate why `strtoll()` may have failed. [Per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.3), the `printf()` function does no set `errno` on error, so `printf()` is [free to modify the value in `errno`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."